# Output filename extension in fswatch and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, sh, fswatch

I'm having issue with the file-naming extension output. My input is JPG files that needs to convert to MP4 using FFMPEG. However, when I run the code below it output as `img1.jpg.mp4` including the input file extension instead of just `img1.mp4`.

```
fswatch -e ".*" -i "\\.jpg$" . |xargs -n1 basename|xargs -n1 -t -I {} sh -c 'pwd;[[ -f {} ]] && ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "{}" -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=2:d=1" -preset "ultrafast" -c:v libx264 -t 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p "{}.mp4"'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Running on MAC, SH/BASH

**EDITED:**

BTW I also tried a loop to do the trick like the code below, but I'm looking to more neat solution to fix it in the same line of code above or call function after `FSWATCH` successful operation.

```
 for file in
     *.jpg.mp4; do
        mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .jpg.mp4).mp4"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this with `sed`:

```
fswatch -e ".*" -i "\\.jpg$" . |
xargs -n1 basename |
sed 's/\.jpg$//' |
xargs -n1 -t -I {} sh -c 'pwd;[[ -f {}.jpg ]] && ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i "{}.jpg" -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=2:d=1" -preset "ultrafast" -c:v libx264 -t 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p "{}.mp4"'
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Looks like sed is not working with fswatch, does this need any dependencies?